# input error of lstm with keras

Tags: keras, lstm, keras-layer, recurrent-neural-network

I meet exactly the same question as you. I also followed the guide of @td2014 but finally an error appears. My input shape is (24443, 124, 30), my lstm layer is set as follows:

```
model = Sequential() 
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape = (1, 30), return_sequences = True)) 
model.add(Dense(1)) 
model.add(Activation('softmax')) 
model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam') 
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epoch = 1, batch_size = 124, verbose = 2)
```

The error I get is "Error when checking input : expected lstm_4_input have shape (None, 1, 30) but got array with shape (24443, 124, 30)"

Do you have some suggestions for that?

Comment: Like: change `input_shape=(124, 30)` ?

Comment: I tried as you said, a new error appears "Error when checking target: expected activation_23 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape(24443, 124)"  Doesn't a number in this place represent the time_step? I planned to feed one vector one time and 124 vectors as a sequence. or maybe I understand the input in a wrong way...

Comment: Yeas, I think you are misunderstanding the input or maybe I'm not understanding you, anyway lstm inputs should be `(batch_size, steps, features)`, where steps is the length of each sequence you are feeding the model.

Comment: By the way, batch_size is the number of samples or the number of sequences for one batch?